# Convert the multiple columns in the dataframe to a single column using pandas

Tags: pandas

i have datafarme input as follows and i want to convert to the output format

```
A         B          C       D       E       F  
Fruits  apple       val1    val2    NaN     val4
Fruits  mango       val1    val2    NaN     val4
Fruits  jack fruit  val1    val2    NaN     val4
Fruits  pomegranate val1    val2    NaN     NaN
Fruits  kiwi        val1    val2    NaN     NaN
Fruits  plum        val1    val2    val3    NaN
Fruits  banana      val1    val2    val3    NaN
Fruits  grapes      val1    val2    val3    NaN


output:
-------
Fruits  apple           val1
Fruits  mango           val1
Fruits  jack fruit      val1
Fruits  pomegranate     val1
Fruits  kiwi            val1
Fruits  plum            val1
Fruits  banana          val1
Fruits  grapes          val1
Fruits  apple           val2
Fruits  mango           val2
Fruits  jack fruit      val2
Fruits  pomegranate     val2
Fruits  kiwi            val2
Fruits  plum            val2
Fruits  banana          val2
Fruits  grapes          val2
Fruits  plum            val3
Fruits  banana          val3
Fruits  grapes          val3
Fruits  apple           val4
Fruits  mango           val4
Fruits  jack fruit      val4
```

and i need the columns to create seperate rows based on the values in the column using pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set_index` followed by `stack`

```
df.set_index(['A', 'B']).stack().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html)

```
d = df.melt(["A", "B"], ["C", "D", "E", "F"])
d.drop('variable', axis=1, inplace=True)
d.dropna()
```

Output:

```
         A            B value
0   Fruits        apple  val1
1   Fruits        mango  val1
2   Fruits    jackfruit  val1
3   Fruits  pomegranate  val1
4   Fruits         kiwi  val1
5   Fruits         plum  val1
6   Fruits       banana  val1
7   Fruits       grapes  val1
8   Fruits        apple  val2
9   Fruits        mango  val2
10  Fruits    jackfruit  val2
11  Fruits  pomegranate  val2
12  Fruits         kiwi  val2
13  Fruits         plum  val2
14  Fruits       banana  val2
15  Fruits       grapes  val2
21  Fruits         plum  val3
22  Fruits       banana  val3
23  Fruits       grapes  val3
24  Fruits        apple  val4
25  Fruits        mango  val4
26  Fruits    jackfruit  val4
```

Comment: but i dont know the column names because n columns will be present.

Comment: @userD1989 if you don't know the column names but `A` and `B` would still be there as they are, you can replace `["C", "D", "E", "F"]` with `df.columns[2:]` in the call to `melt`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
l1 = [ df[['A','B',i]].rename(columns={i:'value'}) for i in ['C','D','E','F']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in l1:
   df1 = df1.append(i)

df1 = df1[~pd.isnull(df1['value'])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
         A            B value
0   Fruits        apple  val1
1   Fruits        mango  val1
2   Fruits   jack fruit  val1
3   Fruits  pomegranate  val1
4   Fruits         kiwi  val1
5   Fruits         plum  val1
6   Fruits       banana  val1
7   Fruits       grapes  val1
8   Fruits        apple  val2
9   Fruits        mango  val2
10  Fruits   jack fruit  val2
11  Fruits  pomegranate  val2
12  Fruits         kiwi  val2
13  Fruits         plum  val2
14  Fruits       banana  val2
15  Fruits       grapes  val2
16  Fruits         plum  val3
17  Fruits       banana  val3
18  Fruits       grapes  val3
19  Fruits        apple  val4
20  Fruits        mango  val4
21  Fruits   jack fruit  val4
```

Comment: It's best practice to avoid loops like this (although doing so is sometimes impossible or exceedingly difficult when talking about more complicated derivation functions).